# How can I add one parameter to add() function

Tags: cakephp

Surely I can add a parameter like add($pid). and call like control/add/4.
 But when any validation error , it collapses and tell
"missing argument 1 for ConsultingDetsController::add()"
From where cakePHP default add() is calling and how to solve this issue?
thanks...

Comment: make sure your URL is in the form of `http://www.example.com/control/add/4` and NOT `http://www.example.com/control/add/` , otherwise it will throw that

Comment: The form's action also must be `control/add/4`, so that when you submit it, if there are any validation errors, it will reload with the correct ID in place. Also consider using a hidden field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write a function, and want to pass a variable in the URL, you'd write it like this:

```
public function add($pid) {
    //...
```

But - if written like that, ANY time you try to access this function, you MUST have that variable, or you'll get the error you mentioned.

If you'd like to be able to access the function and SOMETIMES pass it a variable (like when you're submitting a form, and don't necessarily need the URL variable for example), **just set the value of the parameter**:

```
public function add($pid = null) {
```

Doing this will allow you to call the function via `controller/add/4` or `controller/add` and will not cause an error.

Then, just make sure you verify $pid has data before trying to use it for something important:

```
if(!empty($pid)) {  //or something similar, depending on your data
```